# How to make a flutter app to be open with a custom URL?

Tags: android, flutter, default, mobile-application

I am working on a flutter app. We see that some apps like Facebook opens on clicking on the default domain name. Default apps for some domain names.

For example, clicking on `facebook.com/foo` opens the Fb application. How can we enable this in a flutter app? What is basic working happens there? Is there any code needed to make it happen on a flutter app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use App-link / deeplink in your app to launch from a link .
[App Link](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links), [Uni Link](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) and [deep link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking) will help you a lot .
basically you have to analyse you requirements because you can achieve this by dynamic link, deep link and app link and these all look same but have their own functionalities so choose wisely which one is best for you.

Answer (score -1):

you can use firebase dynamic link check this link
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/dynamic-links/overview/